# How to use external library with love2d

Tags: lua, love2d, luarocks

I'm trying to use the `luafun` library with `love2d`.
Running `lua main.lua`, however `love .` complains about the missing `fun` library.

I have installed `luafun` with `luarocks`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two options.

If you want to distribute whatever you're building, you almost certainly don't want users to install Lua, luarocks, etc. etc. - so the best way is to simply put any libraries into the folder that your game/program/… lives in.  (If a library contains compiled things, you'll need to build per platform/OS and then you'll actually want a build process that spits out the various variants, but if it's all-Lua, there's no platform-specific stuff, so just copy it in.)

The other option (mostly for when you only need it to work on your machine) is to adjust `package.path` and then `love` will find things just fine.  If you use `LUA_INIT` / `LUA_PATH` on your machine, Love ignores them but you can manually fetch & process them using `os.getenv`, `dofile` / `load(code)()` & friends.  (As the very simplest special case of this, if luarocks is installed in the standard Lua search path, saying `require "luarocks.loader"` might be enough to get all luarocks-installed packages to work.)